# Shortcut for finding cases where .Intersect .Count > a threshold?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 collections and I'd like to determine whether or not the number of intersecting elements is above a certain threshold.

I currently use this code (which is executed approx. 85 million times so speed *does* matter):

```
public bool isSimilarTo(....)
    int numberOfSharedPoints = pointsA.Count(pointsB.Contains);
    if (numberOfSharedPoints >= THRESHOLD) return true;
```

This strikes me as potentially inefficient since `numberOfSharedPoints` has to be calculated first.

Is there a more optimal way, for example, iterating through the elements with a `break` shortcut when the threshold is achieved?

Bonus questions:

1. Would `this.pointsA.Intersect(pointsB).Count()` be faster for the first line of code?
2. The collections are currently `List<>` - would a `Hashset` be faster?

Comment: What sequence of items is shorter? `pointsA` or `pointsB`? This matters, since join always buffers right sequence.

Comment: Either sequence may be shorter, this varies and is not known at design time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out if the intersection has more or equal number of items than the `THRESHOLD` you can use this construct:

```
if (pointsA.Intersect(pointsB).Skip(THRESHOLD - 1).Any())
{
    //...
}
```

As pointed out by [Rawling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215380/rawling) in the comments under another answer, [`Intersect`](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/16-Intersect.html) will fully enumerate only the second sequence. So the complexity of this solution is seems to be `O(n + m)` - `n` and `m` being the numbers of items in `pointsA` and `pointsB` collections resp. `O(m)` is the cost of constructing a `HashSet` - so I'm assuming that this kind of structure is used internally. Checking whether an element is inside a hash set is constant time (as pointed out by [Ilya Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283124/ilya-ivanov) in the comments), and it's done at most `m` number of times for the worst case scenario (for example: when the intersection is empty all elements need to be checked).

Also, if you have concrete collections with constant time `Count` you can try the following optimization, if it's possible that their sizes may differ significantly:

```
var shorter = pointsA;
var longer = pointsB;

//makes sense if Count() is constant time
if (shorter.Count() > longer.Count())
{
    shorter = pointsB;
    longer = pointsA;
}

if (longer.Intersect(shorter).Skip(THRESHOLD - 1).Any())
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a sample to find out performance of each answer given here including the traditional `foreach` loop:

In my sample console application I generated 10,000 random floating point numbers for `pointsA` and `pointsB`.
Threshold count is 100, and checked performance of each method, with the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double totalTimeSpentIntersectAndSkip = 0;
    double totalTimeSpentHashSet = 0;
    double totalTimeSpentCount = 0;
    double totalTimeSpentWhereAndSkip = 0;
    double totalTimeSpentForEach = 0;
    int maxIteration = 1000;
    for (int j = 0; j < maxIteration; j++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            pointsA.Add(r.NextDouble());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            pointsB.Add(r.NextDouble());
        }

        s.Reset(); s.Start();
        var timeSpentInSeconds = TestUsingIntersectAndSkip();
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("IntersectAndSkip: " + timeSpentInSeconds);
        totalTimeSpentIntersectAndSkip += timeSpentInSeconds;

        s.Reset(); s.Start();
        timeSpentInSeconds = TestUsingHashSet();
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("HashSet: " + timeSpentInSeconds);
        totalTimeSpentHashSet += timeSpentInSeconds;

        s.Reset(); s.Start();
        timeSpentInSeconds = TestUsingForEach();
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ForEach: " + timeSpentInSeconds);
        totalTimeSpentForEach += timeSpentInSeconds;

        s.Reset(); s.Start();
        timeSpentInSeconds = TestUsingWhereAndSkip();
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("WhereAndSkip: " + timeSpentInSeconds);
        totalTimeSpentWhereAndSkip += timeSpentInSeconds;

        s.Reset(); s.Start();
        timeSpentInSeconds = TestUsingCount();
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Count: " + timeSpentInSeconds);
        totalTimeSpentCount += timeSpentInSeconds;

        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        pointsA.Clear();
        pointsB.Clear();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Following is Average TimeSpent by each method: "+Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine("IntersectAndSkip: " + totalTimeSpentIntersectAndSkip / maxIteration);
    Console.WriteLine("HashSet: " + totalTimeSpentHashSet / maxIteration);
    Console.WriteLine("ForEach: " + totalTimeSpentForEach / maxIteration);
    Console.WriteLine("WhereAndSkip: " + totalTimeSpentWhereAndSkip / maxIteration);
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + totalTimeSpentCount / maxIteration);
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");


}
static Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
const int THRESHOLD = 100;
static List<Double> pointsA = new List<double>();
static List<Double> pointsB = new List<double>();

private static double TestUsingHashSet()
{
    HashSet<double> hash = new HashSet<double>(pointsA);
    hash.IntersectWith(pointsB);
    if (hash.Count >= THRESHOLD)
    {
        return s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    }
    else
    {
        return s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    }
}

private static double TestUsingWhereAndSkip()
{
    if (pointsA.Where(pointsB.Contains).Skip(THRESHOLD - 1).Any())
    {
        return s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    }
    else
    {
        return s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    }
}

private static double TestUsingCount()
{
    int numberOfSharedPoints = pointsA.Count(pointsB.Contains);
    if (numberOfSharedPoints >= THRESHOLD)
    {
        return s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    }
    else
    {
        return s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    }
}

private static double TestUsingForEach()
{
    var intersectItemCount = 0;
    foreach (var d in pointsA)
    {
        if (pointsB.Contains(d)) intersectItemCount++;
        if (intersectItemCount > THRESHOLD)
        {
            return s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }
    return s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
}

private static double TestUsingIntersectAndSkip()
{
    if (pointsA.Intersect(pointsB).Skip(THRESHOLD - 1).Any())
    {
        return s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    }
    else
    {
        return s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

I run this 1000 times and stored results for each iteration and average results, after all this analysis following is the ranking by performance:

```
1) Intersect with Skip
2) HashSet
3) Count (Given by OP)
4) Where and Skip
5) Foreach
```

[image]

When changing item count from 10,000 to 50,000 (5 runs) all are taking too much time except `HashSet` and IntersectWithSkip. The performance ranking remains almost same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(pointsA.Where(pointsB.Contains).Skip(THRESHOLD-1).Any()){
   //...
}
```

Comment: nice one. You should probably note, that `pointsA` evaluates lazily, while `pointsB` should be of type `IList` (better yet to use `HashSet`). The last point is already true, but it would be very nice in having `pointsA` as `IEnumerable`, if it's longer

Comment: @IlyaIvanov No, `Intersect` only fully reads the second sequence. The first sequence is still lazily evaluated. [Link](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/16-Intersect.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get O(n) with a sorted IEnumerable as you only have to make one pass
This is Integer but you could use a generic and pass a comparer
In my test the CompareSS below beat ss1.Intersect(ss2).Skip(thresHold1 - 1).Any() by 5:1
Yes 5 times as fast

With two HashSet and a ForEach Contains you could also get O(n) compare but HashSet is more expensive to create.

```
public static void TimeTest()
{
    int size = 20000;
    List<Int32>ss1 = new List<int>(size);
    List<Int32>ss2 = new List<int>(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Int32 int1 = i;
        Int32 int2 = i + (Int32)((float)size / 2);
        ss1.Add(i);
        ss2.Add(int2);
    }
    //foreach (int iTest in ss1)
    //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(iTest);
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
    //foreach (int iTest in ss2)
    //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(iTest);

    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    int thresHold1 = (Int32)((float)size / 4);
    int thresHold2 = (Int32)((float)size * 3 / 4);

    Int32 matchcount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        if(CompareSS(ss1, ss2, thresHold1))
            matchcount++;
        if (CompareSS(ss1, ss2, thresHold2))
            matchcount++;
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("sw.ms {0}   count {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0"), matchcount.ToString("N0"));
    sw.Restart();
    matchcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        if (ss1.Intersect(ss2).Skip(thresHold1 - 1).Any())
            matchcount++;
        if (ss1.Intersect(ss2).Skip(thresHold2 - 1).Any())
            matchcount++;
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("sw.ms {0}   count {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0"), matchcount.ToString("N0"));
    sw.Stop();

}
public static bool CompareSS (IEnumerable<Int32> ss1, IEnumerable<Int32> ss2, Int32 threshold) 
{
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("threshold {0}", threshold);
    using (var cursor1 = ss1.GetEnumerator())
    using (var cursor2 = ss2.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!cursor1.MoveNext() || !cursor2.MoveNext())
        {
            return false;
        }
        Int32 int1 = cursor1.Current;
        Int32 int2 = cursor2.Current;               
        int count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("int1 {0}   int2 {1}", int1, int2);
            int comparison = int1.CompareTo(int2);
            if (comparison < 0)
            {
                if (!cursor1.MoveNext())
                {
                    return false;
                }
                int1 = cursor1.Current;
            }
            else if (comparison > 0)
            {
                if (!cursor2.MoveNext())
                {
                    return false;
                }
                int2 = cursor2.Current;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
                if (count >= threshold)
                    return true;
                if (!cursor1.MoveNext() || !cursor2.MoveNext())
                    return false;
                int1 = cursor1.Current;
                int2 = cursor2.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If speed is important, use the following.

```
HashSet<T> hash = new HashSet<T>(pointsA);
hash.IntersectWith(pointsB);
return hash.Count;
```

You shouldn't use LINQ in performance-critical situations if it's possible to use concrete collections.

Alternatively, try to get the elements in the form of sets in the first place.

Comment: "You shouldn't use LINQ in performance-critical situations." and why is that?

Comment: Because it simply performs badly. This is because it usually involves many redundant operations, as a lot of work has to be repeated to get, for example, the number of itersecting items.

Comment: Really? Any evidence for that, or it's just your suspicion? It surely performs badly when it's used in a wrong why without understanding how it works. Otherwise I didn't noticed any obvious penalty for using LINQ instead of a `foreach`. In this case you may be right, but your statement in general is false.

Comment: What about lazily evaluating sequences? Try doing it **manually**, and your head starts to boil (mine sure does). Reading only 300 from a sequence of 1000000 items may increase performance greatly.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov that is true; if the sequence is lazy, there isn't much you can do about it. However, the author is specifically talking about collections of some kind.

Comment: You can iterate lazily over collections and lists too ;)

Comment: @BartoszKP Sometimes there is no penalty for using LINQ. A good example is how the `Count()` method is implemented. It checks if the underlying collection implements `IList` and if so, returns its `Count` property (assumed to be `O(1)`). However, in general, LINQ makes no guarantees for performance. This optimization isn't documented anywhere and certainly doesn't work for some collection types. Because LINQ may or may not have to do needless operations, and you wouldn't know unless you decompiled it or considered it too much, you shouldn't use it in performance critical situations.

Comment: Also, I'm mainly talking about using `LINQ` versus using concrete collections. I'm not really talking about implementing your own operations with `foreach`. That really wouldn't be any faster, unless you had a lot of nested LINQ queries going on or something.

Comment: "`LINQ` versus using concrete collections." ? This doesn't make sense. Collections are data structures, LINQ contains algorithms. There's no sense in comparing that. And yes, most of the time, an alternative to LINQ is some form of explicit iteration - like `foreach`. And this implies that the general statement in your answer is false. "Sometimes there is no penalty for using LINQ" What penalty are you talking about? You haven't proven that any penalty exists yet. Talking about exceptions to a non-existent rule is a bit hasty ;)

Comment: You often have a choice between working with concrete collections, such as `HashSet<T>`, or working with sequences (that may or may not actually be collections) by using LINQ methods. This choice is demonstrated by the different answers people gave to the problem.

I've mentioned two performance problems already; the first, that you need to count a lazy sequence one by one to get the number of intersect items, and the second using the `Count()` LINQ method on something that may be a collection already.

Comment: This algorithm will perform *worse* than the LINQ solutions provided.  This will fully enumerate all sequences in all cases; the LINQ solutions provided short circuit and edit as soon as they have found a solution.  While you could add such functionality without using LINQ, not having done that, this won't perform as well.

Comment: @GregRos "...that you need to count a lazy sequence one by one to get the number of intersect items, ...". Sorry, but you still fail to distinguish between algorithms and data structures. If an `IEnumerable<T>` is not a collection but some sort of lazy sequence, then with or without LINQ you have no other option to count its elements (or do anything else that needs to "see" all of them) than evaluating them one by one. Regarding your second statement: using `Count()` on a collection is optimized in LINQ - it verifies the type of underlying collection and uses constant time `Count` if possible.

Comment: @Servy That is not true. My solution will iterate over every sequence at most once; the same statement is not true for some of other solutions. `Intersect` does iterate over each sequence at most once, though.

Comment: @GregRos This will perform worse than the top voted answer.  It does perform better than King King's solution, yes.

Comment: Run some time test on this.  That new statement is costly.